# Need help to write web api wrapper for Silverlight project

Tags: c#, webclient, silverlight-5.0, asp.net-web-api

Please bear with me as I am new to Silverlight. I need to write a web api wrapper (I've named it `WebClientWrapper`) which is supposed to consume rest services. The project uses **Silverlight 5**. I am facing many problems while writing such a wrapper. There are a lot of examples demonstrating rest service consumption in C#. But unfortunately none of them worked for me. It's been a challenge for me to get done with what I need. Below are my requirements:

1) UI should not freeze while I make any GET request,

2) Calling methods from `WebClientWrapper` should be as easier as possible.

3) .NET framework version of project should not be changed.

**I tried following things so far**:

1) Use of [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx). I referred this link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client. The problem with this approach is I cannot call ReadAsAsync method. Calling this method requires change in framework (i.e. replacing dlls or changing framework version) which is not feasible.

2) Use of [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). [http://www.kastory.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=25:rest-web-service-in-c-with-silverlight-and-asp-net-web-api&catid=32:web-services&Itemid=130](http://www.kastory.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=25%3arest-web-service-in-c-with-silverlight-and-asp-net-web-api&catid=32%3aweb-services&Itemid=130).
The problem with this is I will probably (not sure!) have to make changes in the way I call methods from WebClientWrapper. I am trying to accomplish calling method from WebClientWrapper something like this:

```
var appointments = WebClientWrapper.Get<Appointments>(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"hospitalId", "19465654546"}
        }, "appointment");
```

Below is the code snippet I tried in WebClientWrapper.

```
private const string BaseUrl = "http://localhost:63455/api";

    private static WebClient GetClient()
    {
        int leadingInt = new Random().Next(10000, 99999);
        int trailingInt = new Random().Next(1000, 9999);
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddHHmmMMssMMyyyyyss");
        string ticketString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", leadingInt, date, trailingInt);

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Accept"] = ticketString;
        client.Headers["UserAgent"] = "ReceptionistApp";

        return client;
    }

    private static void DownloadCompletionHandler<T>(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Encoding messageEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (T));
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(messageEncoding.GetBytes(e.Result));
        var objectToReturn = (T) serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(Dictionary<string, string> paramDictionary, string controller)
    {
        string absoluteUrl = BaseUrl + controller + "?";
        absoluteUrl = paramDictionary.Aggregate(absoluteUrl,
            (current, keyValuePair) => current + (keyValuePair.Key + "=" + keyValuePair.Value + "&"));
        absoluteUrl = absoluteUrl.TrimEnd('&');
        WebClient client = GetClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadCompletionHandler<T>;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(absoluteUrl));
    }
```

**Below are the things I want to mention regarding the code above**:

1) As obvious, compiler throws error for the method `Get<T>` since I've not returned object of type `T`.   How shall I get that object from `DownloadStringAsync`? I know I can use `DownloadStringTaskAsync`. But it is not available with the current framework. What changes do I have to make in my code so that I get `appointments` as shown in the `Get<Appointments>` method call?

2) `DownloadCompletionHandler<T>` is bound to return `void` but actually I want to return `objectToReturn` as shown in code.

Help will be greatly appreciated. Any new code snippets that will fulfill my requirements are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) helped me instead of WebClient.